# Register an event handler for a CSS class using jQuery does not work when elements are added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a simple, elegant way to create a "delete" button for a user's comments on a site I'm working on.

Ideally, I'd like to register an event handler for a class called something like "delcomment" and then assign a unique id to individual comments' delete buttons. Soemthing like the following:

```
<div>Wow really great post! <span class="delcomment" id="2350">delete</span></div>
<div>I think so too! <span class="delcomment" id="2351">delete</span></div>
<div>I think so too! <span class="delcomment" id="2352">delete</span></div>
```

And then use jquery to register an event handler for the class (somehow). This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. This code works when elements are hardcoded HTML, but doesn't work when elements are added dynamically:

```
// register event handler for delcomment
$( "span.delcomment" ).click(function() {
    // some code that actually deletes comment from database
});
```

Any thoughts on best practice here? I would prefer to avoid any use of onclick="deleteComment(2350)" in each span, just to keep JS/JQ and HTML in separate sections of the document.

Comment: What doesn't work? That seems like it should work fine to me.

Comment: @dwhite.me How does that make a difference here?

Comment: i would use delegation ($.on) so that you don't need to rebind the events every time the view updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written your code works. So there must be another reason for it not working.

Either the DOM isn't ready in which case wrap the click handler in the DOM ready callback

```
$(function(){
 // register event handler for delcomment
 $( "span.delcomment" ).click(function() {
  // some code that actually deletes comment from database
 });
});
```

Or these elements are being added dynamically, in which case you would delegate the click event to that specific class

```
// register event handler for delcomment
$( "body" ).on("click", "span.delcomment", function() {
 // some code that actually deletes comment from database
});
```

This delegation works by assigning a handler to the body element itself, and then every time a click event is registered, it looks to see if the target element matches the given selector. If it does, then the callback function is called (and internally `.bind` is used to make that target element equal to `this` in the callback).

Comment: Mentioning the dynamic nature of elements is also a good idea (even if the OP didn't mention it).

Comment: You were correct; comments were being added dynamically via AJAX. The second suggestion worked! I did have to wrap it in document.ready(). Bonus question: care to explain how/why the second snippet of code works?

Answer (score 2):

> This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. This code doesn't work:

This would work as expected:

```
<div>Wow really great post! <span class="delcomment" id="2350">delete</span></div>

// register event handler for delcomment
$( "span.delcomment" ).click(function() {
  // some code that actually deletes comment from database
});
```

> Any thoughts on best practice here?

However I would change a few things to:

- separate concerns of styles and javascript by prefixing javascript classes (js-)
- encapsulate each element and move data values to appropriate locations
- remove the specificity of which html tag is the delete button, this means that the html can change (span->div->input->button) without affecting the function
- prefix data values with data- (html5) to enhance collection of values (jquery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/))
- upgrade to the latest version of event binding [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

html file (php/perl/aspx/cshtml whatever):

```
<div class="js-comment" data-comment-id="2350">Wow really great post! 
  <span class="js-btn-delete">delete</span>
</div>
```

Js code file (page.js):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $( ".js-comment .js-btn-delete" ).on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $comment = $this.closest(".js-comment");
    if ($comment.length == 1)
    {
      var $comment-id = $comment.data('comment-id');
      //do logic
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, there were a lot of good tips here for further exploration. I'm off to do some reading on HTML5 "data-," ".closest()" and more. Also, do you prefix JS classes with "js-" just so that you don't rename them and break your code?

Comment: Lets say that you have a UI/UX guy who wants to change the classes on an html tag for styling.  With this nomenclature he can add and remove whatever he wants as long as they don't start with `js-`.  Additionally no styles should exists in any style sheet that start with `js-`, and it's pretty easy to enforce.  He doesn't break functionality, and whoever is doing the JS doesn't break styles because there are no styles that rely on `js-`.